# Raspberry PI BTLE can discover a Fitbit and a Scale device, but cannot pair

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez, raspberry-pi4, btle

I have been attempting to pair a [FitBit Inspire HR](https://www.fitbit.com/us/products/trackers/inspire?sku=413BKBK) and a [RENPHO ES-26R](https://renpho.com/products/renpho-es-26r-bluetooth-digital-body-weight) scale with my Raspberry Pi (3B+, 4B, and Zero), all with the same negative results. Running **bluetoothctl** (v5.50), the devices can be seen (**ED:67** is the scale, **01:C5** is the Fitbit) :

```
...
[CHG] Device ED:67:37:60:78:22 ManufacturerData Key: 0xffff
[CHG] Device ED:67:37:60:78:22 ManufacturerData Value:
  aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 00 01 23 14 ff ff ff 14  ...g7`x"..#.....
  00 6a 04 4d a2 02 1d 0c                          .j.M....
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 RSSI: -47
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 TxPower: 3
...
```

### SCALE

When I attempt to pair or connect the scale, the outputs from bluetoothctl, hcidump, and gatttool are as follows:

**bluetoothctl**

```
Attempting to pair with ED:67:37:60:78:22
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

**hcidump**

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Remove Device From White List (0x08|0x0012) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
```

**gatttool**

```
> sudo gatttool -b ED:67:37:60:78:22 -I
[ED:67:37:60:78:22][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to ED:67:37:60:78:22
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

Per a few threads I've seen, I've tried using the address type of both public and random, with no change. The hcidump doesn't seem to have a lot going on for the Scale.

## EDIT

Inspecting the Scale further, it appears that it is not "connectable". Given that there are no defined services or characteristics, I started looking at the "**manufacturing data**" in the **Advertisement**.  I can see that as the measurement on the scale changes, portions of the data are changing:

```
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 00 00 4d a2 02 8a 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 d2 00 4d a2 02 8b 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 d2 00 4d a2 02 8b 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 60 04 4d a2 02 8b 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 68 06 4d a2 02 8b 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 68 06 4d a2 02 8b 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 ad 07 4d a2 02 8c 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4d 7f 7e 3a 14 00 ad 07 4d a2 02 8c 25
ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 94 d7 4e 7f 7e 3a 14 00 6b 08 4d a2 02 8c 25
```

Now I just need to confirm that the updated portions are actually weight data - once I figure out what is what in the soup (e.g., unit of measure, weight, etc.).

### FITBIT

For the Fitbit, there are a lot more outputs, but the pairing still fails:

**bluetoothctl**

```
pair 01:C5:59:47:49:F9
Attempting to pair with 01:C5:59:47:49:F9
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 01:C5:59:47:49:F9 Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

**hcidump**

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
    status 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 64 reason 0x16
    Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host
```

**gatttool**

Unlike the Scale, I am able to use gatttool to connect to the Fitbit and retrieve characteristics:

```
[01:C5:59:47:49:F9][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 01:C5:59:47:49:F9
Connection successful
[01:C5:59:47:49:F9][LE]> characteristics
handle: 0x0002, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0004, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0005, uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0006, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0007, uuid: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0008, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0009, uuid: 00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000b, char properties: 0x20, char value handle: 0x000c, uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000f, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0010, uuid: adabfb04-6e7d-4601-bda2-bffaa68956ba
handle: 0x0011, char properties: 0x06, char value handle: 0x0012, uuid: adabfb02-6e7d-4601-bda2-bffaa68956ba
handle: 0x0013, char properties: 0x12, char value handle: 0x0014, uuid: adabfb03-6e7d-4601-bda2-bffaa68956ba
handle: 0x0016, char properties: 0x10, char value handle: 0x0017, uuid: adabfb01-6e7d-4601-bda2-bffaa68956ba
handle: 0x0019, char properties: 0x20, char value handle: 0x001a, uuid: adabfb05-6e7d-4601-bda2-bffaa68956ba
handle: 0x001d, char properties: 0x12, char value handle: 0x001e, uuid: 558dfa01-4fa8-4105-9f02-4eaa93e62980
handle: 0x0021, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0022, uuid: 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0023, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0024, uuid: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0025, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0026, uuid: 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0027, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0028, uuid: 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0029, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x002a, uuid: 00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002b, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x002c, uuid: 00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002d, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x002e, uuid: 00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002f, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0030, uuid: 00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0031, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0032, uuid: 00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

## Additional Information

**Bluetooth Service Status**

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-09 18:32:27 BST; 24min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 5515 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5515 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat --noplugin=sap -E

Apr 09 18:32:27 archer systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 09 18:32:27 archer bluetoothd[5515]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Apr 09 18:32:27 archer systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 09 18:32:27 archer bluetoothd[5515]: Excluding (cli) sap
Apr 09 18:32:27 archer bluetoothd[5515]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

**dmesg | grep Bluetooth**

```
[   12.451287] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.451337] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.452111] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.452123] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.452151] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.462111] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   12.462118] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   12.462172] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   12.462284] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   12.677032] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.677038] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.677048] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  818.140511] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  818.140529] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  818.140542] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

**Connection**

WiFi and Bluetooth both are active on all of the PIs, and I am connected via SSH.

### Closing

I've been walking many, many threads from multiple forums and making various recommended configuration changes (keeping the PI 3B+ clean as a control) with no success. I would much appreciate any advice or pointers on where to go next. There must be something I am missing somewhere - most likely something simple that is making most of you guffaw like you've never guffawed before :)

Thank you for your time in reading this lengthy question.

Comment: Edited: For the Scale, I don't think it can be paired or connected to.  Looks like the weight data may be in the manufacturer data of the advertisement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **Scale**, I was finally able to decode the important values (weight).  There are a few bits which I still do not know what they are, but the main problem was solved. Given the following positions and values:

```
Position:    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
Value:       ff ff aa bb ed 67 37 60 78 22 5e 97 4a 74 7f 7e 3a 15 00 6a 04 4d a2 02 4a 3d
```

The mapping is as follows:

- **0-3**: Unknown at the moment. Values have not been observed to change
- **4-9**: Device Address
- **10-13**: Unix Timestamp
- **14-16**: Unknown at the moment. Values have been observed to change, but not very often.
- **17**: Stabilization indicator.  A value of 0x15 (21) indicates the scale has stabilized the measurement
- **18**: Unknown at the moment. Always appears to be 00
- **19-20**: **The Weight!**. Although the scale displays the weight in Lbs, the transmitted value needs to be divided by 100 to arrive at Kg and can then be converted to other units as needed.
- **21-23**: Unknown at the moment.  The values have not been observed to change
- **24**: Unknown at the moment.  The value changes here and there during measurement, may be related to calculating BMI, etc.
- **25**: Unknown at the moment. The value sometimes changes at various points throughout the day. Does not seem directly related to the measurement itself.

I was - mistakenly - attempting to use the FitBit for sanity; but, obviously the roles and services the two devices fulfill and provide - and how they advertise - are not similar at all, so it was a bad solutioning set :).

I hope this helps anyone else trying to retrieve data from a scale (specifically Renpho ES-26R) which provides its data in the advertisement.  If anyone else comes across the meanings of the unknown bits, please feel free to leave a comment with the information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Great, thank you for the detailed analyses.

I have here a `RENPHO ES-26R-B`. The bytes 24-25 seems to be a counter / index which increses until the measurement is finished, then a previous measurement (smaller idx) is sent multiple times.

I used python with bluepy to read and analyze the messages:

```py
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate


g_idx_old = 0


class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleDiscovery(self, dev, isNewDev, isNewData):
        filter_for_renpho_messages(dev)


def filter_for_renpho_messages(dev):
    for (adtype, desc, value) in dev.getScanData():
        if(desc == 'Manufacturer'):  # idx 255
            if(len(dev.scanData[255]) == 26):
                dev_addr_manufacturer = dev.scanData[255][4:10].hex()
                if(dev.addr.replace(':', '') == dev_addr_manufacturer):
                    # show_all_messages(dev)
                    show_only_stable_weight(dev)


def show_all_messages(dev, write_to_file=False):
    manufacturer_data = dev.scanData[255]
    weight_raw = int.from_bytes(manufacturer_data[19:21], "little")
    weight_kg = float(weight_raw)/100.0
    index_raw = int.from_bytes(manufacturer_data[24:26], "little")
    # print the data
    print("{} {} {} {:6.2f}kg {:5}".format(
        datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), dev.addr,
        dev.scanData[255].hex(), weight_kg, index_raw))
    # write the data to file (binary)
    if(write_to_file):
        with open("manufacturer_data.bin", "ab") as data_file:
            data_file.write(manufacturer_data)


def show_only_stable_weight(dev, write_to_file=True):
    global g_idx_old

    manufacturer_data = dev.scanData[255]
    weight_raw = int.from_bytes(manufacturer_data[19:21], "little")
    weight_kg = float(weight_raw)/100.0
    idx = int.from_bytes(manufacturer_data[24:26], "little")

    # only show weight if the incoming idx is smaller than a prev
    if((idx < g_idx_old) and          # stable result has smaller idx
       ((g_idx_old - idx) < 50000)):  # ignore overflow
        # print the data
        print("{} {:6.2f}kg".format(
            datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), weight_kg))
        # write the data to file (CSV)
        if(write_to_file):
            filename = "weights.csv"
            # If file is new, set the header row
            if not os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open("weights.csv", "a") as csv_file:
                    csv_file.write("timestamp;datetime;weight;kg\n")
            # append current measurement
            with open("weights.csv", "a") as data_file:
                data_file.write("{};{};{};kg\n".format(
                    int(time.time()), datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"), weight_kg))
    g_idx_old = idx


def main():
    scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
    scanner.scan(timeout=None, passive=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In function `show_all_messages` it is possible to write the data to a binary file which can afterwards analyzed with the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime


with open("manufacturer_data.bin", "rb") as dump_file:
    data = dump_file.read()
    data_len = len(data)
    print("Datalen: {}\n".format(data_len))
    for i in range(int(data_len / 26)):
        cur_data = data[i*26:(i+1)*26]

        # strange, timstamp is big endian, but weight and idx are little endian
        timestamp_raw = int.from_bytes(cur_data[10:14], "big")
        weight_raw = int.from_bytes(cur_data[19:21], "little")
        index_raw = int.from_bytes(cur_data[24:26], "little")
        weight_kg = float(weight_raw)/100.0

        print("{} | {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} | {} {:5} {:5} | {:6.2f}kg".format(
            cur_data.hex(),
            cur_data[0:4].hex(),    # always "ffffaabb"
            cur_data[4:10].hex(),   # device address "ed67388f9d27"
            cur_data[10:14].hex(),  # timestamp
            cur_data[14:17].hex(),  # Unknown "ffffff"
            cur_data[17:18].hex(),  # Stabilization? "12" or "13"
            cur_data[18:19].hex(),  # Unknown "a0"
            cur_data[19:21].hex(),  # weight
            cur_data[21:24].hex(),  # Unknown "4f2e03"
            cur_data[24:26].hex(),  # idx / cnt
            datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_raw).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            weight_raw,
            index_raw,
            weight_kg))
```

Here is an example for the analyzed data:

```
                                                                                                  weight        idx                       weight  idx
                                                                                                   ||||        ||||                        ||||  ||||
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9cffffff12a0ae1f4f2e039e1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9c ffffff 12 a0 ae1f 4f2e03 9e1d | 2021-01-23 00:15:40  8110  7582 |  81.10kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9cffffff12a0ae1f4f2e039e1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9c ffffff 12 a0 ae1f 4f2e03 9e1d | 2021-01-23 00:15:40  8110  7582 |  81.10kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9cffffff12a002214f2e039e1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9c ffffff 12 a0 0221 4f2e03 9e1d | 2021-01-23 00:15:40  8450  7582 |  84.50kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9cffffff12a002214f2e039e1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9c ffffff 12 a0 0221 4f2e03 9e1d | 2021-01-23 00:15:40  8450  7582 |  84.50kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9dffffff12a0e51f4f2e039f1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9d ffffff 12 a0 e51f 4f2e03 9f1d | 2021-01-23 00:15:41  8165  7583 |  81.65kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9dffffff12a00d204f2e03a01d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9d ffffff 12 a0 0d20 4f2e03 a01d | 2021-01-23 00:15:41  8205  7584 |  82.05kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9dffffff12a00d204f2e03a01d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9d ffffff 12 a0 0d20 4f2e03 a01d | 2021-01-23 00:15:41  8205  7584 |  82.05kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9fffffff12a008204f2e03a31d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9f ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a31d | 2021-01-23 00:15:43  8200  7587 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5c9fffffff12a008204f2e03a41d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5c9f ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a41d | 2021-01-23 00:15:43  8200  7588 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca0ffffff12a008204f2e03a51d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca0 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a51d | 2021-01-23 00:15:44  8200  7589 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca0ffffff12a008204f2e03a61d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca0 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a61d | 2021-01-23 00:15:44  8200  7590 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca0ffffff12a008204f2e03a61d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca0 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a61d | 2021-01-23 00:15:44  8200  7590 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca1ffffff12a008204f2e03a71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca1 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 a71d | 2021-01-23 00:15:45  8200  7591 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca2ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca2 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:46  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca2ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca2 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:46  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca2ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca2 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:46  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca3ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca3 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:47  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca4ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca4 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:48  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca4ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca4 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:48  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca4ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca4 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:48  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca4ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca4 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:48  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5ca5ffffff13a008204f2e03a21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5ca5 ffffff 13 a0 0820 4f2e03 a21d | 2021-01-23 00:15:49  8200  7586 |  82.00kg
...

ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb1ffffff13a000004f2e03be1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb1 ffffff 13 a0 0000 4f2e03 be1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:01     0  7614 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb1ffffff12a05d204f2e03be1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb1 ffffff 12 a0 5d20 4f2e03 be1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:01  8285  7614 |  82.85kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb1ffffff12a035204f2e03be1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb1 ffffff 12 a0 3520 4f2e03 be1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:01  8245  7614 |  82.45kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb1ffffff12a035204f2e03be1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb1 ffffff 12 a0 3520 4f2e03 be1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:01  8245  7614 |  82.45kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb1ffffff12a008204f2e03be1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb1 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 be1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:01  8200  7614 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb2ffffff12a008204f2e03bf1d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb2 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 bf1d | 2021-01-23 00:16:02  8200  7615 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb2ffffff12a008204f2e03c01d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb2 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 c01d | 2021-01-23 00:16:02  8200  7616 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a0451f4f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 451f 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03  8005  7617 |  80.05kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a0ca1c4f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 ca1c 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03  7370  7617 |  73.70kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a0600e4f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 600e 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03  3680  7617 |  36.80kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a0600e4f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 600e 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03  3680  7617 |  36.80kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a0600e4f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 600e 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03  3680  7617 |  36.80kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a000004f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03     0  7617 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a000004f2e03c11d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c11d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03     0  7617 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a000004f2e03c21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c21d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03     0  7618 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb3ffffff12a000004f2e03c21d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb3 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c21d | 2021-01-23 00:16:03     0  7618 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb4ffffff12a000004f2e03c31d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb4 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c31d | 2021-01-23 00:16:04     0  7619 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb4ffffff12a000004f2e03c31d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb4 ffffff 12 a0 0000 4f2e03 c31d | 2021-01-23 00:16:04     0  7619 |   0.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a06c204f2e03c51d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 6c20 4f2e03 c51d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  8300  7621 |  83.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0b41e4f2e03c51d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 b41e 4f2e03 c51d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  7860  7621 |  78.60kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0b41e4f2e03c51d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 b41e 4f2e03 c51d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  7860  7621 |  78.60kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0ae1f4f2e03c51d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 ae1f 4f2e03 c51d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  8110  7621 |  81.10kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0df204f2e03c61d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 df20 4f2e03 c61d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  8415  7622 |  84.15kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0bd1f4f2e03c61d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 bd1f 4f2e03 c61d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  8125  7622 |  81.25kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb5ffffff12a0bd1f4f2e03c61d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb5 ffffff 12 a0 bd1f 4f2e03 c61d | 2021-01-23 00:16:05  8125  7622 |  81.25kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb6ffffff12a0e01f4f2e03c71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb6 ffffff 12 a0 e01f 4f2e03 c71d | 2021-01-23 00:16:06  8160  7623 |  81.60kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb6ffffff12a0e01f4f2e03c71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb6 ffffff 12 a0 e01f 4f2e03 c71d | 2021-01-23 00:16:06  8160  7623 |  81.60kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb6ffffff12a008204f2e03c71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb6 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 c71d | 2021-01-23 00:16:06  8200  7623 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb6ffffff12a008204f2e03c71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb6 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 c71d | 2021-01-23 00:16:06  8200  7623 |  82.00kg
ffffaabbed67388f9d27600b5cb6ffffff12a008204f2e03c71d | ffffaabb ed67388f9d27 600b5cb6 ffffff 12 a0 0820 4f2e03 c71d | 2021-01-23 00:16:06  8200  7623 |  82.00kg
...
```

Comment: Awesome detective work and nice script! I adapted it so that measurements are being published via MQTT. I know the MAC address of my scale so the constant wild scanning is probably not needed.